# How to know all available methods and how to use them

Tags: api, magento-community, code, programming, methods

I'm still learning how to use Magento and I see that it has lots of useful methods. However, my only way of learning that a method exists, and how to use it, remains looking at code that's already done, asking, or searching in the Internet.

How should I do when I need something specific? In the official documentation in Magento's webpage there is not a complete reference. It's not like in Java, with Javadoc, for example.

How did you do, when you were in learning phase, to know what is available to use? Is there any website with good information about that?

Comment: Did you check here http://www.polcode.com/en/8-best-resources-to-learn-magento-for-developers/ or https://www.flinttechnology.co.uk/recommended_magento_blogs/

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Magento then first use this link

1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/

These links are useful for the customization

1. http://inchoo.net/category/magento/
2. http://excellencemagentoblog.com/
3. http://blog.chapagain.com.np/about/